# PHP , send email

Tags: php, email

I probably have this completely wrong but when I try to run this code , I want to send the template email to the user , this work perfect on my local server but now that uploaded to my site to the host it just sends a blank email. I left my password and email l out if this code btw .

```
<?php

    function format_email($info, $format){

        //set the root
        $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dolearnfinance.com/email_templates';

        //grab the template content
        $template = file_get_contents($root.'/signup_template.'.$format);

        //replace all the tags
        $template = preg_replace('({FNAME})', $info['fname'], $template);
        $template = preg_replace('({EMAIL})', $info['email'], $template);
        $template = preg_replace('({KEY})', $info['key'], $template);
        $template = preg_replace('({SITEPATH})','http://www.dolearnfinance.com', $template);

        //return the html of the template
        return $template;
    }

    function send_email($info){

         //format each email
        $body = format_email($info,'html');
        $body_plain_txt = format_email($info,'txt');
        $email = $info['email'];

        //setup the mailer
        // Create the Transport
        $transporter = Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com', 465, 'ssl')
          ->setUsername('*')
          ->setPassword('*')
          ;

        /*
        You could alternatively use a different transport such as Sendmail or Mail:

        // Sendmail
        $transport = Swift_SendmailTransport::newInstance('/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs');

        // Mail
        $transport = Swift_MailTransport::newInstance();
        */

        // Create the Mailer using your created Transport
        $mailer = Swift_Mailer::newInstance($transporter);


        // Create a message
        $message = Swift_Message::newInstance('Verifi Email')
          ->setSubject('Welcome to doLearnFinnace')
          ->setFrom(array('noreply@doLearnFinnace.com' => 'doLearnFinnace'))
          ->setTo(array($email))
          ->setBody($body_plain_txt)
          ;

        // Send the message
        $result = $mailer->send($message);
        return $result;


    }

?>
```

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- how will implement this Fred. Thanks for reply

Comment: @AmyHyland Maybe your host is blocking the ports or other scripts. Put this under the `<?php` tag `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and  `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and see what errors you got.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Make sure that the template exists where you think it does on the server. Is there a folder at `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dolearnfinance.com/email_templates'` ?

Comment: Does not show any thing . Yes it defiantly exist , it was working just fine maybe it would the host , but it just sends a blank email that why i dont think it is the host

Comment: Is ther another way to do this maybe

Comment: It seems that it not entering the funtion format_email  i tried echo a java script alert just to see but seems to be doing noting

Comment: The `dolearnfinance.com` in `$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'dolearnfinance.com/email_templates';` if that is indeed a folder of that name, should have a `/` for it `$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/dolearnfinance.com/email_templates';`. - You also mention JS but you didn't show us that. You could also try echoing the functions, I.e.: `$body = echo format_email($info,'html');` and the same for the others. If the functions aren't being executed, it's most likely because they're not being called correctly or could be a variable scope issue. That's about all that comes to mind for me here.

Comment: Addendum to above: If you don't have folder of that name, then remove it `$root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/email_templates';` and a site "path" `$template = preg_replace('({SITEPATH})','http://www.dolearnfinance.com',` is a path, not a URL and looks to be a constant that is defined somewhere. Plus, try adding dots `$template .= preg_replace...` etc. for all except the first one which my *"Spidey sense"* is tingling on for some reason ;-)